# Setting Session Handler in Joomla to none

Tags: session, joomla, handler

Our joomla site is using 1.7.3, and having performance issues when there are a number of users on line, as well as database corruption issues. The table being corrupted is the _session table.

I would like to try and turn off the session handling, and therefore set the session handler in Joomla Global Configuration to "None" from "database".

Can this cause other issues? What is the possible consequences of doing this?

Thanks,

ken

Answer (score 1):

To answer your direct question - yes there will be lots of problems from turning session handling off especially in an areas of interactivity with users. Most things will break, such as:

- Any `/administrator` functionality
- Registering users
- Forms
- Polls
- Front-end article editing etc
- anything like JomSocial or similar products

The corruption in #_session is usually caused by failed writes to the DB because the host isn't keeping up with the load - if you are getting these problems during high load time you will have to consider a better hosting package/service.

More importantly the 1.7.x series is no longer supported, you should [upgrade to 2.5.3](http://www.joomla.org/announcements/release-news/5416-joomla-253-released.html) as it fixes a very nasty pair of exploits that leave all prior version vulnerable to hackers.

Comment: Nope, when you set the session handler to none it uses the PHP session handler:
https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.Session.Storage.None.html

I'm using the none option my self and don't experience any of these issues.
Also see this question on stackexchange: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/334/session-handler-database-or-none

Answer (score 0):

If you set the session handler to none Joomla will use the session handler that is build into PHP.

If PHP is installed and configured properly then setting the session handler to none shouldn't cause any issues.

When using a load balancing cluster that isn't session aware you would want to use the database option. So that all servers can access the session data from the database.
In all other cases you can use the none option, which should (theoretically) be faster because the sessions are on the local server and don't have the overhead of setting up a database connection. Additionally I believe PHP has the file cached in memory which would mean it can access the session list virtually instantaneous.